# Javascript Callback Function

Tags: javascript, callback

Here's the problem, I'm trying to do an automatic test to see if addToCart() works correctly.

```
addToCart();
if(Kiosk.GetCart().toString() !== emptyCartString){
    setTestResults('addToCart', 'Passed');
}
else{
    setTestResults('addToCart', 'Failed');
}
```

I'm adding a product to an empty cart, then I want to check to see if the cart is still empty, if something is there then addToCart() worked and the test has passed.  If the cart is still empty after the addToCart() call then the test should fail.

What is happening is that the addToCart() method takes a while to execute and in the meantime the 'if' statement fires and checks the cart before addToCart() has a chance to return, and thus the test always fails.

Callbacks are the answer, correct?  But what's the best way to implement them here?

Comment: Is the `addToCart` method asynchronous? The way the question is worded makes it sound like `addToCart` returns right away before the item is added, but then "returns" again when it's done (which can't happen)... Is it making an AJAX request? Regardless, the test code should only be executed when the item is done being added to the cart -- and yes, callbacks are one way to achieve this, but we need to know more about your specific scenario before we can suggest an implementation.

Comment: First, my apologies for an imprecise question, and thanks for looking at it.  I'm using jQuery and C# as well for this particular solution.  The addToCart method uses a getJSON request and then calls a C# method, so yes, it is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I maybe don't quite understand the question, but what's wrong with passing the callback to the `addToCart` function and having that function call the callback when it's done?

Like this:

```
addToCart( function() {
    if(Kiosk.GetCart().toString() !== emptyCartString){
        setTestResults('addToCart', 'Passed');
    }
    else{
        setTestResults('addToCart', 'Failed');
    }
} );
```

Comment: This seemed like the most straight-forward approach I've read about, sadly it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly did you do? Why exactly didn't it work? Where did you receive an error and what error was that?

Answer (score 0):

As I think, function addToCard will post / get to server using ajax. Then add the code

```
if(Kiosk.GetCart().toString() !== emptyCartString){
    setTestResults('addToCart', 'Passed');
}
else{
    setTestResults('addToCart', 'Failed');
}
```

To your ajax callback function.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either.  The test continues to fail, but when I check the contents of the cart manually there is something there, so I believe it's still a timing issue.